# Canonical Duplicate Links

Tags: magento-1.9, product-urls, canonical, duplicate

I really don't know a huge amount about duplicate links.

I am told that www.example.com/greenshoe and www.example.com/shoes/greenshoe are duplicate pages and need adjusting. I have added the following code into my product 'greenshoe' under the 'Design' and 'Custom Layout Update':

```
<reference name="head">
<action method="addLinkRel">
<rel>canonical</rel>
<href>https://www.example.com/shoes/greenshoe.html</href>
</action>
</reference>
```

but it doesn't appear to be working. I.e. if I visit www.example.com/greenshoe it's not sending me over to /shoes/greenshoe. Does that make sense? Should it be redirecting the URL and, if so, what am I missing?

I know that 301 redirects are particularly bad for SEO.

Also, as a side note I do have the SEO Canonical turned on in the backend already.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are talking about http://www.adurolabs.com/blog/technical/how-to-add-rel-canonical-in-magento

Comment: Yes, that is where I got the coding from.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to understand what **Canonical URL** means:

In the world of content management and online shopping systems, it's common for the same content to be accessed through multiple URLs. With content syndication, it's also easy for content to be distributed to different URLs and domains entirely.

[More reading from google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en)

**To your question**

Canonical url supposed to tell crawlers to visit or read content from other url than this.

> **Canonical url** setting will not redirect users to other pages.

And crawler may take some time to implement your settings, I suppose you just have to wait little longer.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I was confused because our SEO expert gave this as an example (how there's 2 links for the same page) so I was expecting one of those to redirect.

Comment: However, you shouldn't have two canonical url, one is expected.